# FastReport CrossView does not calculate column width correctly if column header is printer vertically

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

I have a FastReport CrossTab report with long column names, which would expand into multiple pages if I were to print it. I thought maybe I can rotate the column headers in order to save some space. But FastReport does not compute column widths correctly, and the generated report looks like this:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten good help from the Fast-Report website by opening a [ticket](http://support.fast-report.com/).  This seems like the kind of question you might need to ask there.

Comment: The issue was my misunderstanding of how the cross-tab object works

Comment: I for one would be interested in what you discovered if it would not be to big a chore for you.

Comment: I was under the impression that I should provide cross-tab with two master/detail datasets and it would extract the data from them, while cross-tab needs denormalized data.

Comment: I've been fascinated by the correlations that can be derived from digging into data with a crosstab.  I have not tried to do one myself with FastReports, but if I understand correctly then, to do a crosstab, you basically reduce all your data to one large denormalized dataset.  Is that what you have found?

Comment: Exactly. And my mistake was feeding the cross-tab with normalized data. Cross-tab was recalculating column widths for every record in the master dataset separately from the rest.